# Check for empty line using cin

Tags: c++

I want to check for an empty line as an input to perform a specific operation. I tried to use cin.peek() and check if it is equal to '\n', but it does not make sense.

> a
>
> b
>
> c

empty line (here, I want to perform my action)

> a

I have tried this code:

```
char a,b,c;
cin>>a;
cin>>b;
cin>>c;
if(cin.peek()=='\n') {
cout<<a<<endl;
cout<<b<<endl;
cout<<c<<endl;
}
```

Comment: [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)?

Comment: @Xymostech , If you are asking for using getline then check for its length. I prefer to use "cin>>a" because my input will be multiple variable in one line

Comment: Are you reading from a file?

Comment: No from consul @stardust_

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `getline`, then process the string.  If the user entered an empty line, the string will be empty.  If they didn't, you can do further processing on the string.  You can even put it in an `istringstream` and treat it as if it's coming from `cin`.

Here is an example:

```
std::queue<char> data_q;
while (true)
{
    std::string line;
    std::getline(std::cin, line);

    if (line.empty())    // line is empty, empty the queue to the console
    {
        while (!data_q.empty())
        {
            std::cout << data_q.front() << std::endl;
            data_q.pop();
        }
    }

    // push the characters into the queue
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    char ch;
    while (iss >> ch)
        data_q.push(ch);
}
```

Comment: could you please write a simple example to understand you more and illustrate how to extract my input from the string

Comment: @AbdEl-RahmanEl-Tamawy: I added an example that appears to be similar to what you are doing.

Comment: What if the input char is space ' '? Will this code skip this space or take it as an input?                                  std::istringstream iss(line);
    char ch;
    while (iss >> ch)
        data_q.push(ch);

Comment: @AbdEl-RahmanEl-Tamawy: It will skip it, but you can easily modify it to suit your desires. It will not treat it as an empty line, if that is what you are asking.

Comment: Is it must to  empty the queue to the console if the input line was empty ?

Comment: @AbdEl-RahmanEl-Tamawy: No. You can do whatever you want if the line is empty.  You don't even have to have a queue.  I was just showing an example that did something like what I believed your example was trying to do.  My assessment of the intent of your code may not be accurate.

Comment: error: variable 'std::istringstream iss' has initializer but incomplete type !!!? any help?

Comment: @AbdEl-RahmanEl-Tamawy: `#include<sstream>` -- Use [this reference site](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) to determine the appropriate header files to include for whatever facilities you use in C++.