# c++ input double until Enter key is pressed

Tags: c++, double

I have this code that adds up **doubles** entered by the user and stops when the user enters a negative number. I want to change it so that it will stop when the user presses the ENTER key and doesn't enter a number, is this possible? And if so, how?

```
double sum = 0, n;

cout << endl;

do
{
    cout << "Enter an amount <negative to quit>: ";
    cin >> n;

    if(n >= 0)
    {
        sum += n;
    }
}while(n >= 0);

return sum;
```

Comment: This might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15994463/check-for-empty-line-using-cin

Comment: that has to do with strings, i know how to do that, i dont think getline or !n.empty will work because its a double

Comment: sorry for lack of context - the leading answer is why it was suggested.  you can pull it in as a string and then parse a double out of it if the string is nonempty.

Answer (score 2):

Use `getline()` as below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string s;
    double sum=0.0;
    while (1)
    {
        cout<<"Enter Number:";
        getline(cin, s);
        if (s.empty())
        {
            cout <<"Sum is: " <<sum;
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
          sum=sum+ stod( s );
        }
    }    
    return 0;
}
```

An example output:

```
  Enter Number:89
  Enter Number:89.9
  Enter Number:
  Sum is: 178.9
```

Comment: @beginnerjohn I changed my answer

Comment: stoi identifier not found i tried including string and sstream and it didnt work, also the conversion has to be to a double not an int

Comment: @beginnerjohn `stoi` and `stod` functions added to `C++` in `standard=c++11`. I think you use `Standard= c++98`, right?

Comment: stod identifier not found

Comment: im using visual c++ 2008 express

Answer (score 1):

I usually never do >= because this can get messy especially when you need to find the median or mode. For the code above this is how I would go about doing it.

```
  double sum =0;
  double n =0;

  while(cin >> n) // this will keep going as long as you either enter a letter or just enter
  {
      sum += n; // this will take any input that is good 

      if(!cin.good()) // this will break if anything but numbers are entered as long as you enter anything other then enter or a number
        break;

  }
```

Comment: okay, I just ran the code and it works as long as you press anything other then Enter or a number it will cancel out and break

Comment: yes it works that way, is there anyway to end it by pressing the Enter key?